# How to create a debian/watch file?

Tags: debian, package-management, watch

Debian has a file called watch file which is used for keeping track of new releases.

I tried to create a watch file to see how it works from the Debian [wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/debian/watch#GitHub) and tried to copy the same for a game project called unknown horizons. The game is there in [Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/unknown-horizons) but as can be seen there is no watch/file so the maintainers do not know when a new version has come up.

The new releases come up at https://github.com/unknown-horizons/unknown-horizons/releases

I tried winging it by doing the following -

```
$ cd tmp 

/tmp $ mkdir unknown-horizons 

/tmp/unknown-horizons $ mkdir debian
```

Then going to -

```
$ cd /usr/share/doc/unknown-horizons

/usr/share/doc/unknown-horizons $ cp changelog.Debian.gz /tmp/unknown-horizons/debian 

/tmp/unknown-horizons/debian $ gunzip changelog.Debian.gz
```

and then finally attempting to make the watch file

```
/tmp/unknown-horizons/debian $ [$] cat watch                                                                                                                      
     1  version=3
     2  opts=filenamemangle=s/.+\/v?(\d\S+)\.tar\.gz/<unknown-horizons>-$1\.tar\.gz/ \
     3  https://github.com/unknown-horizons/unknown-horizons/releases .*/v?(\d\S+)\.tar\.gz
```

Now it is very much possible that I may have bungled in the watch file more than once as I just copied and pasted from the wiki page. I don't really know or understand the perl regular-expressions

The new release is at https://github.com/unknown-horizons/unknown-horizons/archive/2017.1.tar.gz

I did try to test if the watch file worked or even if it errored out but this is the output it gives -

```
/tmp/unknown-horizons $ uscan --verbose --report

uscan info: uscan (version 2.17.0) See uscan(1) for help
uscan info: Scan watch files in .
uscan info: Check debian/watch and debian/changelog in .
uscan warn: Problems reading debian/changelog in ., skipping
uscan warn: No watch file found
uscan info: Scan finished
```

Now I could have understood if it had said that the watch file had some issue but to say no watch file found, no idea what's happening.

Anybody has an idea what the issue might be ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're going about things in this way, given your previous questions. To start making your changes, without using too much disk space, I'd suggest

```
apt-get source --diff-only unknown-horizons
tar xf unknown-horizons_2014.1+git160920-1.debian.tar.xz
```

This will give you the full `debian` directory, with an appropriately-named `changelog`. You'll also notice then that there *is* a `watch` file, containing:

```
version=3
opts="filenamemangle=s/(?:.*)?v?(\d[\d\.]*)\.tar\.gz/unknown-horizons-$1.tar.gz/" \
         https://github.com/unknown-horizons/unknown-horizons/releases (?:.*/)?v?(\d[\d\.]*)\.tar\.gz
```

As you can see, when following the wiki's instructions you need to replace all of `<project>` with the project name, including `<` and `>`.

You can even tell that there is a `watch` file just from the [tracker](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/unknown-horizons); it says at the very top of the screen

> A new upstream version is available: [2017.1](https://github.com/unknown-horizons/unknown-horizons/archive/2017.1.tar.gz)

which means that the package contains a `watch` file (that's how the tracker knows there's a new upstream version).

Comment: damn, for some reason I was not able to see that, sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

In source packages the changelog file should be named `debian/changelog`. Just rename it.